# Error installing mongodb community version 64 bit on win 8

Tags: mongodb, windows-8

I downloaded and installed mongodb but on running the mongod.exe or any other binary files, throws an error of missing api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll.

[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestion how to avid it or any other way to install mongodb??

Comment: I've installed an early binary release and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yet no clue why 3.6 not working.